# sed + how to tell sed to ignore appending when lines already exists?

Tags: linux, bash, sed, perl

we want to add the following lines before the match word - `exec` in launcher file

```
export  JAVA_HOME=/usr/jdk64/jdk1.8.0_112
export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
```

the launcher file

```
more  launcher
.
.
.
exec "$(dirname "$0")/launcher.py" "$@"
```

so we create the following sed line

```
 sed -i '/^exec/i export  JAVA_HOME=/usr/jdk64/jdk1.8.0_112\nPATH=${JAVA_HOME}/bin:$PATH' launcher
```

the problem is that the second or the third time when we run the above sed line then sed append anew lines , so we get duplicate lines as

```
export  JAVA_HOME=/usr/jdk64/jdk1.8.0_112
PATH=${JAVA_HOME}/bin:$PATH
export  JAVA_HOME=/usr/jdk64/jdk1.8.0_112
PATH=${JAVA_HOME}/bin:$PATH
exec "$(dirname "$0")/launcher.py" "$@"
```

is it possible to tell sed to ignore appending when lines already exists? , ( or with perl one liner )

one option is to clean the lines with:

```
sed -i '/JAVA_HOME/d' launcher
```

and then

```
 sed -i '/^exec/i export  JAVA_HOME=/usr/jdk64/jdk1.8.0_112\nPATH=${JAVA_HOME}/bin:$PATH' launcher
```

but want to know also if we can do it inside the above sed line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll simplify and call your exec line just "exec" and the prepending lines (with the exports) "pre1" and "pre2".

You could "skip" two lines on /pre1/ by loading them in the hold space and do the "empty" command `b`:

```
 sed '/pre1/{N;N;b};/exec/ipre1\npre2'
```

That way the command for `/exec/` is only run when `/pre1/` is not matched.

Assumes of course that you have either

```
 pre1
 pre2
 exec
```

or just

```
 exec
```

only and never "pre1" or "pre2" in other order, only one of them, or any of them somewhere else in the file.

Comment: Nice solution, if `pre1` can't appear in another context in the file. Just one remark, that this is not portable, because most `sed` flavours will interpret everything after the `b` as branch label. So either do `sed -e '/pre1/{N;N;b' -e '};/exec/ipre1\npre2'` or use `n`: `sed '/pre1/{n;n;n;};/exec/ipre1\npre2'`

Comment: Good point, `n` is safer, especially since the script might be more complex.

Comment: Feel free to include it in your answer